# Which architecture to adopt when working with tile layers and Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: gdal, leaflet, tiles, cartesian

I'm currently working on a webmapping application dedicated to warehouse management. Where data is based on indoor geolocation and **Cartesian coordinates system**.

More precisely, the map background is built from a LiDAR survey. I have a dedicated backend that creates a raster file then generate tiles with the [gdal2tiles-leaflet](https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet) script.

My web client consume these tiles with Leaflet `TileLayer`.
But since my GeoJSON objects are stored with Cartesian coordinates I needed to set up a conversion mechanism based on [raster-coords](https://github.com/commenthol/leaflet-rastercoords).

My current architecture could be sum up with this diagram:
[image]

But I don't think this implementation is either *efficient* or *robust* (here I think about the conversion work).

So I would like to know if something else different is possible.
I am wondering myself if an other solution wouldn't be to convert coordinates in ***WGS84*** and use ***GeoServer*** to directly serve the tiles as a ***WMS*** service.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to use Leaflet's `L.CRS.Simple` flat (Cartesian) CRS. Here one pixel corresponds to one map unit.

Let's say we want map units that correspond to original rasters map pixels (before it was cut to tiles): one map unit is one pixel on original raster. With tile layer at zoom level 0 whole map is within 256 x 256 pixels, so factor for desired map units is `factor = 256 / maxWidthHeight`, where `maxWidthHeight` is the bigger of raster width and height.

Leaflet will use this factor in all coordinate calculation if we change `L.CRS.Simple` definition by extending it and changing `transformation` method:

```
L.CRS.myCRS = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
  transformation: new L.Transformation(factor, 0, factor, 0)
});
```

Origin of our coordinate system wil be in top left corner, x  going to the right and y down (because third parameter in transformation has positive value) and coordinates will be in the form `[y, x]` (that's how `L.CRS.Simple` is defined).

Let's see how this works on `leaflet-rastercoords` plugin example https://commenthol.github.io/leaflet-rastercoords/example/index.html. Here original raster is 3831 x 3101 pixels, so factor would be `0.06682 = 256 / 3831`. Since actual map at zoom 0 is narrower that tile width (see below), if we want to have lower right corner at `[3101, 3831]`, the correct factor is 0.062495.

[image]

This is the whole code:

```
var width = 3831;
var height = 3101;
var factor = 0.062495;

L.CRS.myCRS = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
  transformation: new L.Transformation(factor, 0, factor, 0)
});
 
var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.myCRS
}).setView([height/2, width/2], 2);

L.tileLayer('https://commenthol.github.io/leaflet-rastercoords/example/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  minZoom: 0,
  maxZoom: 5,
  noWrap: true
}).addTo(map);

map.on('click', function (event) {
  var coords = event.latlng;
  var marker = L.marker(coords).addTo(map);
  marker.bindPopup('[' + Math.floor(coords.lat) + ',' + Math.floor(coords.lng) + ']').openPopup();
});
```

On map click marker is created and popup displayed with marker coordinates.