# Leaflet show layers deformed

Tags: qgis, leaflet

First of all I am pretty new with Leaflet, so I´m sorry if I have obvious fails.

My problem is that the layers loaded by leaflet looks stretched from the top and narrower from the sides.
The first pic is how should look and second how it looks.

[image: This is how it should look correctly]

[image: This is how it should look currently]

The layers were created with QGIS in EPSG:4326. I read default CRS of QGIS is the same.

The code how load the layer is:

```
var singleRoom = this.roomsLayer.features
for (let i = 0; i < singleRoom.length; i++){
            let room = L.geoJSON(singleRoom[i].geometry,{className: "room-"+singleRoom[i].properties})
            this.roomsLayerGroup.addLayer(room)
     }
this.roomsLayerGroup.addTo(this.map)
```

Comment: leaflet uses 3857 by default - neither of those projections are appropriate for maps of building interiors

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So If I change the CRS of shapefile it should fix it?

Comment: I'm kinda tempted to close this as a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321148/which-architecture-to-adopt-when-working-with-tile-layers-and-cartesian-coordina . This kind of use case tends to boil down to using a non-geographical cartesian CRS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this fixed my problem.